# taking the value contained in the brackets using php

Tags: php

for example
the string is my name is xyz(25) 
i want to get 25 in a variable through php..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use preg_match to do it:

```
$string = "xyz(25)";
preg_match("/.*\((\d*)\)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => xyz(25)
    [1] => 25
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think skurpur/phalacee solutions are the most flexible/best approaches, however I found two others:

```
<?php
  $exploded = explode("(", "xyz(25)");
  $yourint = (int)$exploded[1];  
?>

<?php 
  $exploded = (int)substr(strchr("xyz(25)","("), 1);
?>
```

Comment: This will only work for integer values. This will do:

$exploded = explode("(", "xyz(25)");
$exploded = explode("(", "exploded[1]");
$return = exploded[0];